# DateTime.Parse American Date Format C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Probably a simple question -

I'm reading in data from a number of files.

My problem is, that when I'm reading in the date from an american file, I parse it like so:

```
DateSold = DateTime.Parse(t.Date)
```

This parses the string t.Date into a date format, however it formats the american date to a european date, e.g.

If the date is in the file as 03/01/2011, it is read as the 3rd of January, 2011, when it should be the 1st of March 2011.

Is there a way of doing this so that it formats to the european date?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(t.Date, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The DateTime itself has no formatting, it is only when you convert it to or from a string that the format is relevant.

To view your date with American format, you pass the format to the ToString method

```
string americanFormat = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 27):

If you are parsing the date from a file which is specifically a US formatted file then simply pass the US culture information into the parse function as follows;

```
var usCulture = "en-US";
var dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString, new CultureInfo(usCulture, false));
```

This way you can simply swap out the culture string per different region required for parsing. Also, you no longer have to research the specific datetime format nuances for each culture as .Net will take care of this for you as designed.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, at all. OP was asking how to parse a US date to a EU one, you have simply told him how to parse a US date to a US date.

Comment: Brian Scott has done exactly what the OP asked for. The date stored in dateValue is an interpretation of dateString as an American date - but if now it's structured so you can ask for dateValue.Month. If you want to display it in the European style, go ahead and transform it back into a string like shown in the accepted answer. This answer is very helpful since it shows parsing with a different CultureInfo instead of hardcoding the date format.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) when parsing, and specify a format string when you format with `ToString` too.

Note that there's no such thing as "an American date" after it's been parsed. The `DateTime` value has *no* concept of formatting.

It sounds like you're not actually interested in the `Parse` part so much as the formatting part, e.g.

```
string formatted = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

... but I would recommend that you control both the parsing *and* formatting explicitly.

If you have different file formats, you'll need to give different format strings when you read each file. How you then *format* the data is a separate decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the format ahead of time, you can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx), using the American format as your format string.

Answer (score 0):

```
string formatteddate=DateTime.Now.ToString("d") // output: 11/8/2012    
string formatteddate=DateTime.Now.ToString("D") // output: Monday, November 08, 2012    
string formatteddate=DateTime.Now.ToString("f") // output: Monday, November 08, 2012 3:39 PM    
string formatteddate=DateTime.Now.ToString("g") // output: Monday, November 08, 2012 3:39:46 PM    
string formatteddate=DateTime.Now.ToString("d") // output: 11/8/2012 3:39 PM
```

More date-time format in asp.net is given here.

http://dateformat.blogspot.in/2012/09/date-time-format-in-c-aspnet.html

Comment: The questions is about parsing datetime, not about formatting the output. Problem can be solved using an overload of `DateTime.Parse()` method. Specify right culture info: `dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString, new CultureInfo("fr-FR", false));`

Comment: Your 1 and 5 are same but different Outputs, `string formatteddate=DateTime.Now.ToString("d")`. How is that possible?